# Magento transfer problem on another server> show page "shop updating"

Tags: magento-1.7

I tried to transfer my e-commerce on another server, following the normal way:

1) I moved all the files and folder on the new server
2) I did the backup of the database, create a new database on the new server and restored beckup
3) I updated references to new databese on file local.xml
4) I pointed the new domain to the root of Magento

However when I try to access the site from the new domain or if I try to access to the admin area, the site gives me just the update page of the site ("we are updating the store ...").

What's wrong? What should I do?

Comment: is there a file maintenance.flag in the root folder? if so, delete it

Answer (score -1):

With cpanel file manager, goto your site and delete all contents in public_html/var/cache and public_html/var/session.

This should work

Comment: Deleting `var/session` is never an appropiate solution. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94589/keeping-customers-logged-in-after-deleting-var-session